# Datatype mismatch using Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

- Laravel Version: 8.44.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.19
- Database Driver & Version: PostgreSQL 13.3 with pgBouncer

#### Description:

When using `save()` method on PostgreSQL database with `\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true`, DB connection cast boolean to integer in the prepareBindings and bindValues methods.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

```
User::create([
    'name' => 'Laravel user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'is_suspended' => false,
]);
```

Error: `SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: column "is_suspended" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer`

Comment: have toy tried protected $casts = [
  'is_suspended' => 'boolean',
]; in your model

Comment: Already tried. Not working

Comment: Work for me : Laravel 8.36.2 Php 7.5.3 Postgresql 12.7 PgBouncer No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue on PHP8, Laravel 8 with PostgreSQL.
If you use `'false'` or `'true'` or `'1'` or `'0'`, it would work.
However, I'd not rely on such a solution and so the most consistent solution is this

```
User::create([
    'name' => 'Laravel user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'is_suspended' => DB::raw('false'), // now you're not replying on PHP to do anything, instead doing it the database way
]);
```

Make sure to import `DB` `Facade` at the top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```